# Getting Error on DB import

Tags: phpmyadmin, mamp

I have a Drupal environment and got an error, when i tried to import a database dump from the live server to my MAMP (3.5) environment. I checked the table, where the import stopped and tried to import this table by itself.

The table contains drupal cache files. When i try to import the table by itself i’m getting the following error in the apache_error.log:

[Fri Oct 21 10:20:35 2016] [error] [client ::1] FastCGI: comm with server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php5.6.10.fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec), referer: http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/import.php
[Fri Oct 21 10:20:35 2016] [error] [client ::1] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php5.6.10.fcgi", referer: http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/import.php

I’m absolutely not a pro with mysql and all these server stuff, and was so happy, that the MAMP environment worked so fine till now. If i clear all the cache tables before exporting the whole DB on the life server, everything works fine. But i will find out, where the error comes from. The table by itself isn't that huge. It's a 4.5mb file and contains 415 records.
If i reboot MAMP and check the phpMyAdmin all looks fine. I see all 415 records in the corrupt table.

Any ideas? Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your timeout settings in the php.ini.
Just take a look at:

https://timmyomahony.com/blog/MAMP-phpmyadmin-and-big-database-imports-errors-or-timeouts/

Paths can differ due to MAMP version differences. Just search for a php.ini.